# could not find installable ISAM vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oledb

i was having a problem about this . it could not find installbe ISAM i've already change the target cpu in x86 
 [Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTmc4.png)

```
Dim con_excel As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(" Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & TextBox1.Text & "'; Extend Poroperties="" Excel 16.0;HDR=No"" ")
        con_excel.Open()
        Dim qry_excel As String = "Select * from [Sheet1$]"
```

and i already install a AccessDatabaseEngine for this

and im using excel 2016 
should i use this

```
Extend Poroperties="" Excel 16.0;HDR=Yes""
or
Extend Poroperties="" Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes""
```

Comment: Tried https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/209805/you-receive-a-could-not-find-installable-isam-error-message-or-some-fi ? Or any of these: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=could+not+find+installable+isam&oq=could+not+find+installable+ISAM&aqs=chrome.0.35i39j69i60j0l4.5151j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nasty syntax error in your connection string:

```
"'; Extend Poroperties="" Excel 16.0;HDR=No"" ")
```

**`Extend => Extended`**
**`Poroperties => Properties`**

This should be (set `HDR` to whatever is needed. Leave `IMEX=1` for safety):

```
";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"""
```

Change it in:

```
Dim ConnectionString As String =
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & TextBox1.Text &
    ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"""
```

Or:

```
Dim ConnectionString As String =
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=" & TextBox1.Text &
    ";Extended Properties=""Excel 16.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"""

Dim con_excel As New OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
```

Note that `TextBox1.Text` **must** provide the full path to the Excel file.

Download and install the required Database engines (32bit or 64bit).

[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)
[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)

About the `Compile` mode:
Set `Project properties => Compile => AnyCPU`
Set VS `Debug Mode => AnyCPU`

Comment: I was just working out a VB.NET parsing issue where the cell value was blank due to bad type or format detection so I added HDR=YES and IMEX=1 but every time I added those properties it threw this ISAM error. I noticed in your answer you had double quoted the Extended Properties portion of the connection string. All these years I didn't know that! I doubled up my quotes and error disappeared. Thanks for the little detail.

`strConn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1""")`